# jQuery check required input and select

Tags: php, jquery, html-select

I'm losing my battle against my jQuery check :) Can you please help me?

I want to display the 'YES' alert, by checking if all the required fields are filled, so I can go on with the rest of my 'work', there's a hint of PHP in my HTML maybe that's where is my mistake?

HTML :

```
 <div class="col">
    <label for="parent_id" class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Catégorie <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <select name="category_id" id="category_id" class="form-control requiredSel" required>
        <option value="">-- Sélectionnez --</option>
        <?php foreach($parent_categories as $key => $parents):?>
        <optgroup label="<?=$myfofo;?>">
            <?php foreach($parents as $parent): ?>
                <option value="<?=$parent['id'];?>" <?=($parent['id'] == ($post['category_id'] ?? 0)) ? 'selected' : '';?> class=" test"><?=json_decode($parent['title'])->fr;?></option>                                       
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </optgroup>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <label for="parent_id" class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Sous-catégorie <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <select name="subcategory_id" id="subcategory_id" class="form-control requiredSel" disabled data-id-select="<?=$post['subcategory_id'] ?? 0;?>" required>
        <option value="" class="test2"></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And the jQuery :

```
var allRequired = true;
var selRequired = true;
$('.required').each(function(e){
    if($(this).val() == ''){
        allRequired = false;
    }
});
$('.requiredSel').each(function(e){
    if($(this).children("option:selected").val() == ''){
        selRequired = false;
    }
});

if(!allRequired || !selRequired){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('NO');
} else {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('YES');
}
```

I'm guessing it's either because of my PHP, or I'm not targeting the select value correctly..

Thanks you for your time.

Comment: FYI, `$(this).children("option:selected").val()` can be simplified to just `$(this).val()`

Comment: You have some elements with `class="required"` that aren't inputs. What does it mean for a span to be required?

Comment: And spans don't have values.

Comment: It's for CSS purpose, thank for the info Barmar, and to add some details, I got only 5 field to check, the 2 selects, and 3 classics input

Comment: The `required` class is just for the `*` span, it's apparently not the input itself. You need a selector that selects the required inputs.

Comment: Why don't you use `[required]` to match the attribute?

Comment: I'm going to remove the required from my span, because I'm not trying to get the span value lol, sorry, beginner's mistake.

Comment: If you don't count the required on the span, is my jQuery seem correct to you guys if I want to select only the <select> values?

Comment: Yes. And if you add `class="required"` to the inputs, it should work for them as well.

Comment: I'll try, if it work I'll edit to put the correction, thank you really for being patient and for your time.